# For loop Python web-scraping - cycling through a set of URLS with else conditons

Tags: python

I'm having trouble running my loop for web scraping. The main issue is the second part of my code #2. I want to cycle through a set of URLs and scrape information based on the condition the element is present and it contains ".com" or ".id". This works fine however the loop stops after the first URL has been cycled through. I've tried to implement 'finally:' but it hasn't worked.

Code:

```
from cgitb import text
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
from random import randint
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


chromedriver_path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
service = Service(chromedriver_path)
options = Options()

# options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--incognito")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

## Variables

url = 'https://hackerone.com/bug-bounty-programs'
base_url = 'https://'
bountydomains = set()

## Intial Scrape 
## Sleep to load
## find all ul > li tags by class
## Add base url and export as set

driver.get(url)
print('SCRAPING HACKERONE')
sleep(randint(10,12))
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')

for ultag in soup.find_all('ul', {'class': 'program__meta-data list--inline'}):
    for link in ultag.find_all('li', {'class': ''}):
            bountydomains.add(base_url+link.text)
            ## WOKRING 


## Scrape based of url list
## Only finds ul > daisylist > li - text
for link in bountydomains:
    driver.get(link)
    print('Currently Scraping:   ' + link)
    sleep(randint(10,12))
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')


    try: ## Checks to see if the required element is found
        for ultags in soup.find_all('ul', {'class': 'daisy-list'}):
             for links in ultags.find_all('li', {'class': ''}):
                ## Filtering to see if li element text contains .com
            
                if ".com" in links.text or ".id" in links.text:
        
                    print("URL found:" + links.text)
                    driver.quit()
                else:
                    print('No text found url:'   + link )
                    driver.quit()
          

        ## If no element print error
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print ('Element not found for link:' + link)

exit()
```

Comment: shouldn't your try except block be inside your inner most for loop? as those are the elements that you are trying to get -- as for find_all they should return none if none of those tags were found and therefore wouldn't loop for that instance.

Comment: Why are you calling `driver.quit()` within the `if-else` block after checking the first link?  That closes all open webdriver windows